# PhpStorm - Can I auto-indent HTML declared in PHP variables?

Tags: php, phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts, indentation

In PhpStorm, I have a keyboard shortcut on <kbd>Ctrl + I</kbd> linked to the IDE command `Code > Auto-Indent Lines`. That's working fine and I use it way too much.

But there is a specific case where the auto-indent doesn't work, for example:

```
            $result = $this->sortArray($result, NULL, true);
            $buildElement = "<table>";
            foreach ($result as $bill) {
                $stripeColor = stringToColor($bill['transactionStripeStatut']['name']);
                $bill['transactionStripeReturn']['created'] = date('d/m/Y H:i', $bill['transactionStripeReturn']['created']);
                $buildElement .= "
<tr>
<td>{$bill['transactionStripeReturn']['created']}</td>
<td>
<span class='basicTag' style='background-color: {$stripeColor}';'>{$bill['transactionStripeStatut']['name']}</span>
</td>
<td>{$bill['transactionStripeCart']['totalPriceTTC']}€</td>
<td>{$bill['transactionStripeCart']['deliveryMethod']}</td>
<td><a href='{$GLOBALS['websitePath']}/document/facture/{$bill['billHash']}'>Voir la facture</a></td>
</tr>";
            }
            $buildElement .= "</table>";
```

All "multiple lines HTML content" when put in a PHP var are not indented properly. I'm not talking about the **code output**, only **the look in my working file**. I'm not looking for tidy() function, I want to know if there is a way to have HTML in PHP $var indented properly using PhpStorm shortcuts and tools.

Expected result :

```
    $result = $this->sortArray($result, NULL, true);
    $buildElement .= "<table>";
    foreach ($result as $bill) {
        $stripeColor = stringToColor($bill['transactionStripeStatut']['name']);
        $bill['transactionStripeReturn']['created'] = date('d/m/Y H:i', $bill['transactionStripeReturn']['created']);
        $buildElement .= "
            <tr>
                <td>{$bill['transactionStripeReturn']['created']}</td>
                <td>
                    <span class='basicTag' style='background-color: {$stripeColor}';'>{$bill['transactionStripeStatut']['name']}</span>
                </td>
                <td>{$bill['transactionStripeCart']['totalPriceTTC']}€</td>
                <td>{$bill['transactionStripeCart']['deliveryMethod']}</td>
                <td><a href='{$GLOBALS['websitePath']}/document/facture/{$bill['billHash']}'>Voir la facture</a></td>
            </tr>";
    }
    $buildElement .= "</table>";
```

Comment: Nope. You will have to specifically select those lines are indent them to your liking. The reason is very simple: there is **no way** of knowing for the IDE if that leading whitespace is important or not. It's a string and the IDE will not touch its content just like that. **P.S.** Try HEREDOC -- as of PHP 7.3 IIRC it can be indented (aligned by the closing tag) so a leading whitespace to the left of that will simply be ignored by PHP.

Comment: The other option, which I personally fought against for a very long time, is to switch into HTML when you want to “HTML things”. This let’s your IDE do it’s best at doing for the current language. The curl braces in this mode are annoying, but PHP has alternative syntax with the `:` mode. Some people will argue the context switch is a perf issue (which I did, too), but in modern PHP I think it is pretty close to zero.

Comment: @LazyOne Heredoc was a good idea but doesn't solve the problem : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001213759-Ctrl-Shift-L-when-indenting-an-HTML-heredoc Looks like there is curently no support to "Reformat injected fragment".

Comment: @ChrisHaas I can understand closing PHP tags and use "raw" HTML is a solution, but how do you do when you need concatenation or when you're using DOMDocument()  ?

Comment: @Camille But it is exactly the same here: the string already has HTML injected. It just HEREDOC is better for multiline text.

Comment: The issue is caused by anything contained as text in a PHP variable is treated as raw text by PHPStorm, with the exception of some SQL syntax being parsed. In some instances PHPStorm can also parse the HEREDOC by name, such as `<<<HTML` and `<<<SQL` to format them appropriately within their contexts. However, for semantics, it is best to separate and escape PHP variable output from HTML elements. `<td><?php echo htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false); ?></td>`, so that the IDE can understand contextually what is occurring and prevent injection.

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered a limitation of PHPStorm, which is also an intended behavior, you don't really want your IDE to mess around with strings, imagine if it started to indent normal strings that it detects as HTML but are not

For your intent you could use `ob_start`, switch to html and use `ob_get_clean`

```php
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <tr>
         <td><?php echo $bill['transactionStripeReturn']['created'] ?></td>
         ...
    </tr>
    <?php
    $buildElement .= ob_get_clean();
```

Which PHPStorm will be able to indent, but you'll need to use a lot more php tags and echo if there is dynamic data which is more cumbersome to write

An alternative is opening a new HTML scratch file (Long shortcut warning, feel free to customize it: Ctrl+ALt+Shift+Insert)

[image: screenshot of new scratch file]

Paste your string (or heredoc which is better) in this scratch file, it will be automatically formatted on paste, just cut it again and paste it back in the original code
[image: formatted scratch file]